# ASP.NET auto increase number

Tags: asp.net

I would like to write a small app, which basically increases the number by one.

starting at 0 i need to go up to about 8000 and check the http response. Could someone please guide me in the right direction on how to do this?

I currently have the following code which check to see if my image returns a 200, however i need to increase the id by 1, then start again. So 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg, 4.jpg, 5.jpg, up to 8000.jpg.

Before i do this i will be doing a check in the DB to see how many items i need to check. (currently 8000).

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string urlToCheck = "http://localhost/8000.jpg";
    int statusCode = Convert.ToInt32(HttpStatus(urlToCheck));

    Response.Write(statusCode);
}

private static HttpStatusCode HttpStatus(string url)
{
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);

        try
        {
            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                return response.StatusCode;
            }
        }
        catch (System.Net.WebException)
        {
            return HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're doing with the output, but here's how you can generate the sequence of filenames.

```
for (int i = 1; i < 8000; i++) {
    string urlToCheck = string.Format("http://localhost/{0}.jpg", i);
    int statusCode = Convert.ToInt32(HttpStatus(urlToCheck));
}
```

Comment: Perfect Works a treat recursive. All i wanna do is make sure my images are ok, and log ones that are not so i can investigate why :D

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand completely, but if you need to generate a bunch of URLs with different .jpg then this'll do it:

```
var urls = Enumerable.Range(0, 801).Select(id => string.Format("http://localhost/{0}.jpg", id)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 1; i < 8000; i++) 
{
    string urlToCheck = "http://localhost/" + i + ".jpg";
    int statusCode = Convert.ToInt32(HttpStatus(urlToCheck));
}
```